# Fisher Information and Cramér-Rao lower bound problem

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, sampling, parameter-estimation

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are random samples from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, where both $\mu$ and $\sigma \gt 0$ are unknown, and let $\theta = \sigma^p$ for some $p \gt 0$. I want to find the Fisher Information of $\theta$, and the Cramér-Rao lower bound for the variance of any unbiased
estimator for $\theta$.

I am kind of confused of this assumption $\theta = \sigma^p$, and I don't quite know how to deal with it. Any help is welcome

Comment: You can plug in $\sigma=\theta^{1/p}$ into the log likelihood function and then compute the partial derivatives with respect to $\theta$, as in the normal computation of the Fisher information

Comment: Since $\theta$ is a function of $\sigma$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Reparametrization.